# CSP - allowing my own scripts from given directory

Tags: javascript, html, http, security, content-security-policy

I have read several articles about implementing Content-Security-Policy for website, but I still can't figure out how to put it together correctly for my site. Sorry if there is another thread about this, but so far I haven't found one that would help me solving my situation.

I have plain HTML file and I use my own JavaScript to do some rendering on HTML canvas based on user's inpupt.

I have .js files in "js" directory. Currently I am running my website in sub-directory, so I use relative and not absolute path to include them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wbsc-eval.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wbsc-global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wbsc-input.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wbsc-output.js"></script>
```

This is my CSP header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com; script-src 'self';">
```

It allows my own CSS + the Bootstrap one, but my JS is blocked:

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

From what I have read, I thought `script-src 'self'` should allow scripts from the same site, but apparently it is not.

I also tried to set an explicit URL, where my site is currently hosted, but I don't think this is the correct way, as it should be portable + it doesn't seem to work anyway.

Is there some easy and straightforward way to do this? To allow an explicit set of my own scripts and ban everything else?

Adding `'unsafe-inline'` worked, but I have heard it is quite like not having CSP at all and I also encountered some JS operations I was still disallowed to do in my scripts. I think I could count the SHA hash of my JS everytime and pass it to HTML header. But I am constantly changing the scripts during developing, so it doesn't look very convenient. And finally - if there is some easy mechanism for dynamic creating of nonces, I may think of using it. But for my purpose I don't think I need some robust framework, I am doing fine with one HTML + several JS files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts are working fine the problem is `script-src: 'self'` blocks inline script execution, that is inline scripts `<script>alert(1)</script>` and inline event handlers `<img onerror="alert(1)" />`.

You can use the CSP 3 [script-src-attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src-attr) directive in supported browsers but it will be easier (and better) to attach event listeners using `el.addEventListener` or `el.onevent` as Quentin said in the other answer. If  you cant because it is some third party code the one setting attributes with inline event handlers then probably using a `hash` is easier than a `nonce` if you don't mind updating it manually on newer versions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src-attr 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-bhHHL3z2vDgxUt0W3dWQOrprscmda2Y5pLsLg4GF+pI='">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="" onerror="alert(1)" alt="">
  <img src="" onerror="alert(2)" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

This example also works with `script-src` if `unsafe-hashes` is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-http_headers_csp_content-security-policy_unsafe-hashes).

Also check the [Content Security Policy Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html#introduction) and this [pretty nice slides](https://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2019ams/materials/D1T1%20-%20CSP%20-%20A%20Successful%20Mess%20Between%20Hardening%20and%20Mitigation%20-%20Lukas%20Weichselbaum%20&%20Michele%20Spagnuolo.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

> Refused to execute inline event handler

So the problem has nothing (at least nothing directly) to do with the `<script>` elements you are loading.

Somewhere you have something like:

```
<button onclick="call_a_function()">
```

That's an inline event handler.

Replace it with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Thanks a lot for an easy explanation. I favored Isidoro's answer for being more complex for possible future readers, but you got the point as well.